# I have not got vendor folder after installation of composer?

Tags: php, xampp, localhost, composer-php

I tried twice but I am not getting any directory or any vendor folder inside my composer installation.
Although composer is installed successfully. When I am typing composer in CMD Prompt it is displaying a long list.
When I wrote composer -d in CMD "Invalid working directory specified, does not exist.
I want composer for my PHP localhost Xampp
During Installation I selected php.exe file under php folder of Xampp. Installation was smooth
I am currently on 8.1 Windows 64 bit
Kindly Help me this this issue.

Comment: Do you have a composer.json file?

Answer (score 1):

I was going to comment, but apparently I can't right now.

Vendor directory will appear after you have installed a package:

```
composer require somepackage
```

After you've done your installs don't forget to run "composer install -o" to install optimized ClassMap, it will make your autoloading work faster.

Answer (score 0):

To use Composer on your project you need to run it inside your project folder. You can either use composer require as Muhammed M. suggested or write a composer.json file, but all that inside your project folder, not on composer's folder.

If you have a composer.json file, you will run

```
composer install
```

and this will tell composer to install your dependencies. This command will generate your vendor folder with the dependencies inside.

When you run composer commands it will use the XAMP's PHP as you told it to do so during instalation.